# Read and Write from/To same file from different thread using win API

Tags: winapi

I want to open one file from one thread for writing and at the same time open the same file 
in read mode in another thread using Win API.How to achieve without any blocking scenario(means when any write operation going on read operation should not block)

Comment: What do you want to happen when you read and write at the same point at the same time. Do you care what values you read.

Comment: Simply open two handles to the same file, one for writing and one for reading.  Just make sure they have compatible sharing rights to each other.  They will not block each other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - here we can even use one file handle open in asynchronous mode. not need two - only if this easy to use in concrete task

Comment: Don't use one handle. There is only 1 position pointer available per handle. Reading and writing changes the handle's position in the file. You don't want to have to constantly seek the position back and forth to satisfy every individual read and write operation.  That is more work for you, it is more work for the filesystem. Just use two handles instead, then they won't interfere with each other's position.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau :i tried with two handles.one for write a nd one for read.but second time when I tried to open the same file for read it is failing.

Comment: @ David Heffernan: yes I also need to take care about this scenario ....

Comment: @IshanShah: did you notice my earlier comment where I said "*make sure [the handles] have **compatible sharing rights** to each other*"? The write handle needs to enable read sharing.  The read handle needs to enable write sharing. If you are having errors, please show your actual code, you are doing something wrong with it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Ok thanx i will try

Comment: How are you going to deal with the race without blocking? That is unrealistic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: but he only needs to block *when the read and write overlap* which is presumably only a small fraction of the time.  LockFileEx() should do the trick, I think?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: if the handle is opened for overlapped I/O, there is no position pointer - each operation has to specify an offset.  I'm pretty sure RbMm's suggestion would work perfectly well, though I agree that using two handles would be simpler.  (Also, with only one handle, you couldn't use LockFileEx() for synchronization.)